# JQuery autocomplete - Display multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I want to display multiple values to the autocomplete box.
In my understanding JQuery autocomplete uses the key "value" as default to display text to the box.
But I want to display the keys "value", "company" and "tags" which I get by the search result.
Here is what I have:

**My Database query** - Here only ***'value'=>$product->title*** gets used.

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
    $query = $request->get('term','');

    $products = Products::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                      ->orWhere('company', 'LIKE', '%'. $query .'%')
                      ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%'. $query .'%')
                      ->get();


    $data=array();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
            $data[]=array('id'=>$product->id, 
                          'value'=>$product->title, 
                          'company'=>$product->company, 
                          'tags'=>$product->tags);

    }
    if(count($data))
         return $data;
    else
        return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
}
```

**My JQuery autocomplete Script**

```
<script>
$(function()
{
     $( "#search_text" ).autocomplete({
      source: "{{ route('searchajax') }}",
      minLength: 1,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#search_text').val(ui.item.value);
      },
    open : function(){
      $(".ui-autocomplete:visible").css({top:"+=13"});
    },
    });
});
```

**My Input Field**

```
<div class="col">
<input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless ui-autocomplete-input" 
id="search_text" 
type="search" 
name="q" 
value="{{ isset($s) ? $s : '' }}" 
placeholder="Search for Titles, Companys or Tags" 
autocomplete="off" />
```

---

If it helps, I use Laravel for this project.

Comment: Paste your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Ok I will change it. Thought this would be more readable.

Comment: does your first query returning correct data?

 $products = Products::where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                      ->orWhere('company', 'LIKE', '%'. $query .'%')
                      ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%'. $query .'%')
                      ->get();

when you try to die_dump?

Comment: Yes it does: https://i.imgur.com/wtQPF5m.png

Comment: My autocomplete already works, I can search for titles, tags, companys. But just the title gets shown as a result

Answer (score 0):

would it not be easiest to manipulate the 'value' field server side to get the desired result? for example like this

```
'value'=>$product->title.', '.$product->company.', '.$product->tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself with help of the 
[JQueryUI Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem)

I had to manipulate the **renderItem()** extension point.
This is my script now, work perfectly fine:

```
<script>
$(function()
{
     $( "#search_text" ).autocomplete({
      source: "{{ route('searchajax') }}",
      minLength: 1,
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#search_text').val(ui.item.value);

      return false;
      },
    open : function(){
      $(".ui-autocomplete:visible").css({top:"+=13"});
    },
    })
  .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
      .append( "<div><strong>" + item.value + "</strong><br>" + item.company + "</div>" )
      .appendTo( ul );
  };
});
```